# PHP str_replace replace spaces with underscores

Tags: php, str-replace

Is there a reason that I'm not seeing, why this doesn't work?

```
    $string = $someLongUserGeneratedString;
    $replaced = str_replace(' ', '_', $string);
    echo $replaced;
```

The output still includes spaces... Any ideas would be awesome

Answer (score 206, accepted):

I'll suggest that you use this as it will check for both single and multiple occurrence of white space (as suggested by Lucas Green).

```
$journalName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $journalName);
```

instead of:

```
$journalName = str_replace(' ', '_', $journalName);
```

Comment: It uses a [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to match a class of strings in a given pattern, and replaces it with a substitution sequence when matched.

Comment: There is a bug in this version, it will only match groups of more than one space.

Comment: @LucasGreen, you right ! Correct one is : preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $journalName);

Comment: you probably want trim as well:  preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', trim($journalName));

Comment: For UTF-8 encoding use ```preg_replace('/\s+/u', '_', $journalName)```

Answer (score 23):

Try this instead:

```
$journalName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $journalName);
```

Explanation: you are most likely seeing whitespace, not just plain spaces (there is a difference).

Answer (score 12):

For one matched character replace, use **str_replace**:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '_', $string);
```

For all matched character replace, use **preg_replace**:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $string);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead:

```
$journalName = str_replace(' ', '_', $journalName);
```

to remove white space

Comment: How does this differ from the code provided in the question (other than variable names)? `$replaced = str_replace(' ', '_', $string);`